# How to access Attiny84 port B in Arduino IDE code?

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny

Referring to guide at [High-low tech](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695), I were able to flash ATTiny84 via UNO through Arduino IDE 1.6.7.

I loaded a simple blink LED program on IDE pin 0 (physical Attiny84 pin 13, PA0) and everything works fine for pin 0 till 7 at Port A.

But what if I want to access or blink a LED at one of the pins at Port B? Example, PB0 (physical pin 2)

The following is my current code to blink PA7

```
int led=7; //PA7

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to url link by @Mikael, this is the answer I'm looking for.

```
Arduino IDE & Pin Mapping 
// ATMEL ATTINY84 / ARDUINO
//
//                           +-\/-+
//                     VCC  1|    |14  GND
//             (D 10)  PB0  2|    |13  AREF (D  0)
//             (D  9)  PB1  3|    |12  PA1  (D  1) 
//                     PB3  4|    |11  PA2  (D  2) 
//  PWM  INT0  (D  8)  PB2  5|    |10  PA3  (D  3) 
//  PWM        (D  7)  PA7  6|    |9   PA4  (D  4) 
//  PWM        (D  6)  PA6  7|    |8   PA5  (D  5)        PWM
//                           +----+

IDE Attiny84 Physical Pin
  0      PA0           13
  1      PA1           12
  2      PA2           11
  3      PA3           10
  4      PA4            9
  5      PA5            8
  6      PA6            7
  7      PA7            6
  8      PB2            5
  9      PB1            3
 10      PB0            2
```

In order to blink PB0, I would need to replace my code with `int led=2; //PB0`

Comment: Should it not be:
int led=10; //PB0

Answer (score 4):

According to the ATtiny web-page the pin/ports are numbered as below:

[image: ATtiny44/ATtiny84]

The physical pin 2 is the Arduino ATtiny core pin 10. You can also find this well documented in the [pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/damellis/attiny/blob/master/variants/tiny14/pins_arduino.h#L33) file.

Cheers!

Comment: the picture is not what i looking for but the pins_arduino.h does help a lot