# How to declare PB3 reset pin of ATtiny44 in program (using arduino IDE platform)

Tags: attiny, reset

As follow-up of my [former question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92279/how-to-use-reset-pin-as-i-o-pin-with-attiny44/92290?noredirect=1#comment212771_92290):

Hi, I want to know how I can access PB3 reset pin of ATtiny44 IC. I ran out of pins so I am using it as I/O pin, but I am unable to declare it in the code.

[image]

This picture above says that PB3 is pin 11. But if I declare it as pin 11, the reset pin does not function at all.

```cpp
// in setup():
    DDRB |= (uint8_t)(1U << 3);

// in loop():
    PORTB |= (uint8_t)(1U << 3);    // set PB3 to "high"
    PORTB &= ~((uint8_t)(1U << 3)); // set PB3 to "low"
```

This code works with only direct declaration.

In my code I just need to add pin number to the command like `#define CSN 2`.

[image: PB3 of ATtiny]

---

**EDIT**

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>

const int led = 0;

#define led1 11

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);

    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second

    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);

    digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

This is the code that does not work (led1 is reset pin as GPIO). Even if I change the led1 declaration to PB3 of PCINT11, it still does not work.

[image: Fusebits config]

Comment: Show a complete compilable/testable example that demonstrates it affecting the pin using GPIO register manipulation and not affecting it using attinycore's already provided digital pin 11.

Comment: @timemage You can check the edit above

Comment: I see it. That does not look like what I described. Basically I'm looking for an excuse to actually test this. I fully expect if I take the time to dig out my high voltage programmer, and wire it so I can recover from RSTDISBL and I do my own test I will find that digital pin 11 with the correct layout in attinycore will work just fine and the problem is not really as written. If I put in that sort of effort, I'll know I'm not imagining things but I still won't be able to write an answer that I think will solve this for you. It is already documented.

Comment: excuse? i performed my test but the led on the reset remains full OFF and as per the code it should blink whereas, the second led connected to pin13 properly blinks. That is my issue. i have added my fusebit config for your reference.

Comment: I am using damellis library to use arduino as ISP

Comment: By excuse if you mean, the reason behind using reset. The reason is that I ran out of pins and in order to complete the project I need one more GPIO pin and using reset as GPIO is the only solution I can see.

Comment: That may be part of your problem if it leads to incompatible compilation of the sketch. I don't know why you're doing that, attinycore provides for programming via arduino as isp. By "excuse" I mean that I don't want to spend a few hours locating everything just to show that everything behaves exactly as I expected and "the problem is not really as written", like for example what you just said about trying to use two board support packages in a way that may easily screw things up. That was not in the question.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding. I am using just ATtiny44, for programming I am using HVP because I have to disable the reset pin. To write the code I use Arduino platform and I am at the final stage of my program.

Comment: That is in line with my understanding. If information shows in the question that makes me feel like I can replicate your test and I'm not dead-certain that it won't just work for me, I'll take the time recreate the problem here.

Comment: @timemage Ok, so you think that declaring it as pin11 would work

Comment: I have formatted you question a second time, please do not overwrite it again. ;-) -- If the pin works by direct access, as I showed you in the other question, and does not work with the pin number 11, this pin number or the board selection in the IDE do not match. Which board did you select in the IDE? -- Oh, BTW, [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/21508/60431) backs up my assumption that the pin PB3 does no have a pin number.

Comment: @thebusybee, notice they've been trying to use the damellis board package for their programmer definition for some inexplicable reason instead of the attinycore one. i wouldn't be surprised if it's recompiling under a damellis core prior to upload because they've selected that board package to use its version of arduinoisp.ino programmers.txt entry. I fully expect that if set up attinycore with an attinyX4 and use its own programmers.txt entry for arduinoisp.ino, disable reset, and use pin 11 it'll just work fine. so i've been trying to get them to update their question.

Comment: @thebusybee and timemage Hi, just an update, i have resolved my issue. I installed spencekonde attiny Core and it worked for me now i can assign reset pin as 11, use HVP to disable reset. Thank you.

Comment: Great news! Now, to help future visitors (including yourself after some weeks :-P) please write an actual answer and mark it as "accepted".

Comment: @thebusybee Okay, that issue has been resolved and i have written answer as well, i will create another post because i have some other issue now with the same project.

Comment: @thebusybee https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92329/reading-constant-battery-voltage-and-using-the-obtained-value-in-sensor-formula  Could you please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my issue by installing spenceKonde ATtinyCore library, The RESET pin is pin 11 of attiny44 IC and in order to access it inside the code we need attinyCore library not Damellis( damellis does not have RESET programming access).